# Why do passive skills start at 10 instead of 8, like spell save DCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, saving-throw

Passive skills are calculated as *10 + Ability Modifier + Proficiency*, while spell save DCs are calculated as *8 + Ability Modifier + Proficiency*. The opposed roll to both is *1d20 + Ability Modifier + Proficiency*. Why do passive skills get an additional 2 points?

Is there a listed reason for the dissimilarity between Spell Save DCs and Passive Skill Checks? What function does the difference serve in the system?

Comment: Could you give us an indication of what sort of reason you're looking for?  You say 'listed', do you mean to be asking for the reasons the dev team had to make it this way?  Are you asking what the tradeoffs from a game-design standpoint are from having it be 10 v.s. 8?  Are you asking what function the difference serves in the system/what will be different if you change it?

Comment: Ultimately, designer reasons would the best possible answer here if it was obtainable, but in the absence of that, I would be happy with what function the difference serves in the system. If need be, I can ask two questions about a similar topic with those two different qualifiers.

Comment: You should definitely ask this as two different questions. Asking for the designer's reasoning [invokes some fairly strict answering citation requirements](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7876/1204) -- answers are **only** permitted to answer based on cited reasons, zero speculation. Fundamentally what function it serves now that it's present is a whole separate matter unrelated to *why* it was that way -- I'd phrase that as what effect it has on the game such that there's any significance to it. ("what's its function" would invite people to speculate reasons why it was made that way.)

Answer (score 6):

From the [Angry GM](http://theangrygm.com/tweaking-the-core-of-dd-5e/):

> Why do Spell Save DCs use 8 instead of 10? To modify for the fact that MOST creatures and characters are not Proficient in MOST Saving Throws. Of the six possible Saving Throws, PCs are only Proficient with two of them. So, the 8 instead of 10 thing balances that out, favoring the defender and making up for the fact that there aren’t as many good ways to modify Saving Throws as there are to modify Armor Class. The other side of it is that, because magic – the primary source of Saving Throws – cost limited resources (spell slots), magic should be more effective. That is also why many spells also have partial effects, even on a successful save.

Answer (score 3):

#### They represent different interactions.

**Passive Skill Checks** represent the average (give or take 0.5) check for a creature, signifying their acumen when "not actively trying all that hard to do the thing". Think of it as a "stand-in" for an opposed roll. Your Passive Perception, for example, isn't really a Difficulty Check, so much as it is how well you notice thing when you're not actively and specifically looking for them.

**Saving Throw Difficulty Checks** represent the actual intensity (or prowess or finesse or whatever) of the ability attempting to be shrugged off. The Wizard's Fireball DC is a sort of obstacle to overcome, rather than an opposition.

---

As is likely apparent, I have no insight as to designer reasons for this, other than conjecture.

Comment: A good answer and one with which I fully agree. For a bit of RAI flavor, I'd add that passive skill checks represent the average result of something that should realistically be a free action: looking at your surroundings. If allowed infinite free actions (as we are), the average result would be 10.5 + Proficiency + Ability Modifier, which rounds down to 10 + Prof + Mod. Any given active search might be lucky or unlucky, but the average of the thousand glances we make as we go about life is far more consistent.